Baseboard thermostat and thermal cutoff question
I have five 750 Watt 25-year-old baseboard heaters on a 240 volt circuit controlled by an Ouellet OTL221 single pole mechanical thermostat that recently could not be turned down, and the room (and thermostat) became heated significantly and I shut off the breaker.
Can anyone recommend a better type of replacement thermostat to avoid this type of fault and is there any type of thermal cutoff that could be wired downstream of the thermostat as a fail safe to avoid this problem in future? I am concerned that a stuck thermostat could cause a house fire as the heat is so intense. Thank you.

Perhaps you should phrase this as "how do I keep my heaters from burning the house down?" vs. "what sorts of replacement thermostats are out there?"
